# How to randomize the order of radio buttons in pyqt

Tags: python, random, pyqt, qradiobutton

im making a quiz and i want the radiobuttons to be in different positions. ive got it working to a extent as it would be in random order in the first question however it would then stay in that order for the rest of the quiz. I want it to randomize every time.

```
class MultipleChoice(QtGui.QWidget):
showTopicsSignal = pyqtSignal()

def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(MultipleChoice, self).__init__(parent)

    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):
    self.Questions=[]
    self.Questionum = QLabel()
    self.Questioninfo = QLabel()
    self.Correctanswer = QRadioButton()
    self.Incorrectans1 = QRadioButton()
    self.Incorrectans2 = QRadioButton()
    self.Incorrectans3 = QRadioButton()
    self.Correctanswer.setAutoExclusive(True)
    self.Incorrectans1.setAutoExclusive(True)
    self.Incorrectans2.setAutoExclusive(True)
    self.Incorrectans3.setAutoExclusive(True)
    layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(self.Questionum)
    layout.addWidget(self.Questioninfo)
    randomnumber = randint(0,3)
    if randomnumber == 0:
        layout.addWidget(self.Correctanswer)
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans1)
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans2)
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans3)
    elif randomnumber == 1:
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans1)
        layout.addWidget(self.Correctanswer)
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans2)
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans3)
    elif randomnumber == 2:
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans1)         
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans2)
        layout.addWidget(self.Correctanswer)
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans3)
    elif randomnumber == 3:
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans1)         
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans2)
        layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans3)
        layout.addWidget(self.Correctanswer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load your answer choices into a container, you can use Python's `random` ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)) library with one or both of the following tools:

- `random.choice(seq)` ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)) which makes a random choice of the possible items provided in `seq`
- `random.sample(pop, k)` ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)) which choice `k` unique elements from the possible choices provided in `pop`, *without replacing*, which I think is key in your situation because you don't want to have the same answer displayed twice on the same question.

This would simplify your current if-statement block, from

```
if randomnumber == 0:
    layout.addWidget(self.Correctanswer)
    layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans1)
    layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans2)
    layout.addWidget(self.Incorrectans3)
```

to

```
choices = [self.Correctanswer, self.Incorrectans1, self.Incorrectans2, self.Incorrectans3]
for q in range(4):
    layout.addWidget(random.sample(choices, 1))
```

Also just thought of another cool idea. If you have a large "pool" of possible incorrect answers, you can define a function specifically to provide a random selection of wrong answers. Something like:

```
def provideWrongAnswers(self, number):
    return random.sample(self.allWrongAnswersPool, number)
```

which would provide you with `number` incorrect answers to add to the layout along with the correct.

```
In [7]: choices = range(1,11)
In [9]: random.sample(choices, 3)  # returns a different order of choices each time
Out[9]: [1, 7, 3]
In [10]: random.sample(choices, 3)
Out[10]: [6, 9, 3]
In [11]: random.sample(choices, 3)
Out[11]: [5, 4, 2]
In [12]: random.sample(choices, 3)
Out[12]: [3, 6, 1]
In [13]: random.sample(choices, 3)
Out[13]: [10, 8, 3]
In [14]: random.sample(choices, 3)
Out[14]: [1, 7, 2]
In [15]: random.sample(choices, 3)
Out[15]: [9, 7, 3]
```

Finally, `random.shuffle(x)` ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)) be another method, as it takes the sequence `x` and mixes them up in place. So you could combine the `random.sample(wrongChoices, 3)` idea which gives you three random incorrect answers, then add in the correct answer and to make sure the correct answer isn't always at the bottom, give em a final stir with `random.shuffle(allAnswerChoices)`

Comment: FYI, while the documentation for `random.sample()` says it does it without replacement, that is only true for a single call (the results for a single call will never return more than one instance of an element in the initial population). However, it does not modify the input list, meaning the repeat calls to `random.sample` in a loop will likely result in the same element be drawn more than once. You want instead: `for w in random.sample(choices,4): layout.addWidget(w)`

Comment: @TCAllen07 thanks for your answer, i tried the random sample method and i got this error "error layout.addWidget(random.sample(choices, 1))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sample'"

Comment: That error usually means you *assigned* a function as opposed to *calling* the function, such as `print(mystring.lower())` yields `"hello world"` while `print(mystring.lower)` (note the lack of `()` after `lower`) yields `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x107964930>`.  I think you might have **imported** the module wrong, specificaly imported `random.random` instead of just `random`: `import random; random.sample(range(10))` works, while `import random.random; random.sample(range(10))` throws that `AttributeError`. The first `random` is the module, the second `random` is a built-in.

Comment: Oh, and you'll need to use a `for` loop. `random.sample()` returns a list, but `addWidget()` only accepts one widget at a time. so use `c = random.sample(choices);  addWidget(c)` or alternatively just reference the first element of the returned list by adding a `[0]` like so: `addWidget(random.sample(choices)[0])`

Comment: Hey @Spike7, dif this work for you? Or can I further clarify anything? Let me know!

Comment: Yeah it worked, just was confused on what you meant on the imports for a while. but my teacher understood

Answer (score 0):

The current structure of your seems over-complicated. It would be much simpler to randomize the question choices, rather than the widgets themselves.

Here's a simple demo that shows how that could be done:

```
import sys, random
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MultipleChoice(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MultipleChoice, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Questions = [
            ['What is the capital of Bhutan?',
             'Thimphu', 'Bujumbura', 'Suva', 'Kigali'],
            ['What is the capital of Yemen?',
             'Sana\'a', 'Malabo', 'Riyadh', 'Muscat'],
            ['What is the capital of Togo?',
             'Lomé', 'Dakar', 'Abuja', 'Nouakchott'],
            ]
        self.Questionum = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.Questioninfo = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.Questionum)
        layout.addWidget(self.Questioninfo)
        self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.handleChoice)
        for index in range(4):
            button = QtGui.QRadioButton(self)
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(button, index)
            layout.addWidget(button)
        self.buttonNext = QtGui.QPushButton('Next', self)
        self.buttonNext.clicked.connect(self.handleNext)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonNext)
        self.index = -1
        self.handleNext()

    def handleNext(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.Questions):
            self.index = 0
        question = self.Questions[self.index]
        self.Questionum.setText('Question %d:' % (self.index + 1))
        self.Questioninfo.setText(question[0])
        choices = question[1:]
        random.shuffle(choices)
        self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(False)
        for index, choice in enumerate(choices):
            button = self.buttonGroup.button(index)
            button.setChecked(False)
            button.setText(choice)
        self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(True)

    def handleChoice(self, button):
        answer = self.Questions[self.index][1]
        if button.text() == answer:
            print('Right!')
        else:
            print('Wrong...')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MultipleChoice()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but im getting my answers from a table in my database and setting the text each time the next button is pressed. Self.Questions is connected to a mysql query. Could i still incorporate your answer?

Comment: @Spike7. Yes, that's exactly how my answer works. I've used a list of lists to hold the questions/answers, which looks very similar to what you show in your example code. It should be very easy to adapt it.